# Argument resolution inside Global Variable on Bat files

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to use an argument from inside a variable ?

I need to have a global var that will be used at the start of some bat files.

set variable

```
setx var "echo %~n0 %*"
```

sample.bat

```
%var% > lastBatExecuted.txt
set /p last=<lastBatExecuted.txt
if "%last%"=="%~n0 %*" echo it worked
pause
```

I know some ways to solve this problem with work arounds or simple copy paste, but would like to have a one liner that could be put inside a variable.

(length wouldn't be a problem, if i'm still able to just call `%var%`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this method works, but you need to define the variable value with double percent signs, and insert an additional `call` command in order to re-evaluate the percent signs after the first `%var%` expansion. See this test:

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "var=echo One: %%~n0 %%*"
%var%
call %var%

set "var=call echo Two: %%~n0 %%*"
%var%
```

Usage example:

```
C:\> test Arg1 Arg2
```

Output

```
One: %~n0 %*
One: test Arg1 Arg2
Two: test Arg1 Arg2
```

The same behavior should work when the `var` is defined via `setx` command.